# How to use multibyte UTF-8 characters in regular expression groups for preg_match()?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Since I began testing in a PHP 7.2 environment, some of my locale based tests are failing because the currency format for locale de_CH changed.

- Ubuntu 16.04 PHP 7.0: `5'123.81`
- Ubuntu 18.04 PHP 7.2: `5’123.81`

I decided to "improve" my tests, to be able to the different segments separators. The naive approach was to test against the unicode character directly.

```
$this->assertRegExp("@5['’]123\.81@",'5’123.81');
```

which - of course - failed. Later I read about the usage of unicode characters in PCRE (here http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) and that I cannot use the Unicode code point `\u` and have to use the UTF-8 `\x` instead.

But I don't know how to use that in a group:

```
$rightSingleQuotationMarkCode = '\xe2\x80\x99';

// this is fine
$this->assertRegExp("@5{$rightSingleQuotationMarkCode}123\.81@",'5’123.81');

// this is not
$this->assertRegExp("@5['{$rightSingleQuotationMarkCode}]123\.81@",'5’123.81');
```

message:

```
Failed asserting that '5’123.81' matches PCRE pattern "@5['\xe2\x80\x99]123\.81@"
```

I understand, that the group [] doesn't support grouping multibyte characters together. And found a working solution like

```
$testRegExp = "@5'?(?:{$rightSingleQuotationMarkCode})?123\.81@";
$this->assertRegExp($testRegExp,'5’123.81');
$this->assertRegExp($testRegExp,'5\'123.81');
```

But it looks wrong in the way it does the trick and my question is, if  there is any better or smoother integrated solution in PHP PCRE?

Comment: Why didn't you use `u` modifier? Try `$this->assertRegExp("@5['’]123\.81@u",'5’123.81');`. Besides, it is common knowledge PCRE uses `\x{XXXX}` / `\x{XXXXX}` notation.

Comment: Thank you to point that out. The u modifier works for me. But can you provide an example for the \x{} code point? Because `"@5\x{e28099}123\.81@"` prints `Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large at offset 10`

Comment: Yeah, whenever the pattern contains non-ASCII chars, you should add the `u` modifier to make PCRE parse the string as a Unicode string, and treat the literal pattern parts also as Unicode chars, not bytes.